# Data Structure like a Dictionary returns a string when point is in a range

Tags: c#, sql

I have an SQL Query which returns the following table with 3 columns:
[image]

I am searching a data structure, in which I can store the table, that delivers me back the phasename when the dot is between.

I.e. 300 returns Project Management, 360 returns Controlling.

"Project Management"=givePhaseNameFor (300);
"Controlling"=givePhaseNameFor (360);

In SQL I would write

```
WHERE point IS BETWEEN y1 AND y2

public string givePhaseNameFor(int point) 
{
   return "Project Management
}
```

Is there a data structure (like a Dictionary) for this?

Comment: `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, string>`?

Comment: Yes like this, but how can it return a value (i.e. Project Management) when i ask for 300?

Comment: Take the value you get, check where the value is inbetween and then return it? What is the problem you're having with the `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, string>` answer

Comment: Indeed, it would be a lot clearer if you've said "when given a value in the range starting at y1 (inclusive) and ending at y2 (exclusive)".

Comment: @Vulpex: I strongly suspect a list of entries would be better than a dictionary here - then the OP could use a binary search rather than having to check through all entries. There's no point in using a dictionary when you'll never look up by the key.

Comment: @CodeCaster that won't help for a range query

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: The problem is the amount of calls i do not want to penetrate the database so much

Comment: Why you want a dictionary at all? Use `SELECT ProjectManagement FROM Table WHERE @val >= y1 AND @val <= y2`

Comment: @BjörnKarpenstein: But the database can handle it, it should be much faster to find it with proper indexes. You also don't need to handle ongoing synchronization between database and in memory collection(incl. multi threading issues).

Answer (score 2):

No there is not, but you could use something like this:

```
public class RangeList<T>
{
    private List<T> list = new List<T>();
    public abstract int GetLower(T item);
    public abstract int GetUpper(T item);
    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return list.SingleOrDefault(x => index >= GetLower(x) && index <= GetUpper(x));
        }
    }
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (list.Any(x => GetUpper(item) >= GetLower(x) && GetLower(item) <= GetUpper(x)))
            throw new Exception("Attempt to add item with overlapping range");
    }
}

public class Phase
{
    public int y1;
    public int y2;
    public string phasename;
}

public class PhaseList : RangeList<Phase>
{
    public override int GetLower(Phase item)
    {
        return item.y1;
    }
    public override int GetUpper(Phase item)
    {
        return item.y1;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PhaseList phaseList = GetPhaseListFromDB();

return phaseList[300]?.phasename;
```

---

EDIT: An alternate to this would be to create an interface that classes useable in a 'RangeList' must implement. This will mean you don't need a separate inherited list class for each type you want to use.

```
public interface IRangeable
{
    int Lower { get; }
    int Upper { get; }
}

public class Phase : IRangeable
{
    public int y1;
    public int y2;
    public string phasename;

    int IRangeable.Lower => y1;
    int IRangeable.Upper => y2;
}

public class RangeList<T> where T : IRangeable
{
    private List<T> list = new List<T>();
    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return list.SingleOrDefault(x => index >= ((IRangeable)x).Lower && index <= ((IRangeable)x).Upper);
        }
    }
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (list.Any(x => ((IRangeable)item).Higher >= ((IRangeable)x).Lower && ((IRangeable)item).Lower <= ((IRangeable)x).Upper))
            throw new Exception("Attempt to add item with overlapping range");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
RangeList<Phase> phaseList = GetPhaseListFromDB();

return phaseList[300]?.phasename;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Row
{
    public Y1 {get;set;}
    public Y2 {get;set;}
    public Name {get;set;}
}

var list = new List<Row>();
//fill list

var result = list.Where(o => o.Y1 <= x && x < o.Y2).First();
```

Comment: The database would be much faster than this

Comment: @TimSchmelter sure

Comment: The problem is, that i have to do it for a list of 20000 entries :/

Answer (score 0):

if you want speed, I would make two arrays:

- One containing the start ranges
- Another containing the names

Then you would first populate the arrays:

```
int nbRanges = //Get this info from the number of rows in you table
int[] range = new int[nbRanges];
string[] rangeNames = new string[nbRanges];
for (int i = 0; i < nbRanges; i++)
{
    range[i] = //Table.y1;
    rangeNames[i] = //Table.phasename;
}
```

After that, to look for the name is straightforward :

```
public string givePhaseNameFor(int point) 
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index + 1 < nbRanges)
    {
        if (point <= range[index + 1])
        {
            //This means that your point is in the current range
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            index++; //The point is not in this range
        }
    }
    //If we exit without having it found, index == nbRanges and we return the last value
    return rangeNames[index];
}
```